# Sum MAX values of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Situation**:

I have a column (refund) that takes the MAX value for each day so that I don't duplicate the refunds.

```
refund =
var calcul = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Query1[amount]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(Query1[created_at], DateTable[Date]),
            Query1[kind] = "refund",
            Query1[status] = "success"       
            )
```

This works for each day but the total is the max of that column

**Objective**:

I need this measure to calculate the net sales. I have the gross sales measure already but my refund formula doesn't work when aggregated.

**What i tried (thanks to Alexis Olson):**

```
refund =
var calcul = 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Query1[amount]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(Query1[created_at], DateTable[Date]),
            Query1[kind] = "refund",
            Query1[status] = "success"       
            )
    return 
        SUMX(DISTINCT(Query1[orderId]), calcul)
```

However the output is unexpected. It basically takes each value and multiplies it by the distinct count of order ids on that day **(refund or not)**.

So i tried dividing it by the distinct count of order id but the same problem with the total row taking the max value occurs.

Here's the output i get using the provided solution below:

[image: Returns column is correct but total isn't. Refund column is not showing all the values (date relationship issue) but the total works]

Relationships:

Query1[created_at] DateTable[Date] (inactive)

Query1[orderDate] DateTable[Date] (active)

**My returns measure:**

```
Returns = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Query1[amount]),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Query1[created_at], DateTable[Date]),
    Query1[kind] = "refund",
    Query1[status] = "success"       
    )
```

Comment: What does your `Returns` measure look like? Also, is `Day` a table column (if so, what table)?

Comment: day is not a table column. My date column is from my DateTable:DateTable = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(DATE(2018,01,01),TODAY()-1),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of fixing my issue was to use `CALCULATETABLE` before the summarize and then 
use the `SUMX` as suggested above by Alexis.

```
Returns = 
VAR sumary = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            Query1,
            Query1[orderId],
            "maxValue",CALCULATE(
                MAX(Query1[amount]),
                Query1[kind]= "refund",
                Query1[status] = "success"
            )
        ),USERELATIONSHIP(Query1[trx_date],DateTable[Date]))
    RETURN
        SUMX(sumary,[maxValue])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close to something that works. Try changing `calcul` to a summary table instead of a single value scalar like this:

```
refund =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Query1,
        Query1[orderId],
        "MaxValue", CALCULATE (
            MAX ( Query1[amount] ),
            USERELATIONSHIP ( Query1[created_at], DateTable[Date] ),
            Query1[kind] = "refund",
            Query1[status] = "success"
        )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary, [MaxValue] )
```

Comment: for some reason , it doesn't calculate the values for other certain days as if the USERELATIONSHIP isnt working anymore. The suming of the max values work however...

Comment: It's pretty difficult to debug without seeing your data or visualizations. Just shooting in the dark.

Comment: i updated my question with additional information hoping this will help

Comment: @RogerSteinberg It looks like `Day` is level of granularity you are trying to sum over. Try using `Day` instead of `orderId` in the `SUMMARIZE`.

Comment: same issue its as if the userelationship is overriden